# Facebook Graph API - Fetch public event

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to the Facebook GraphAPI, the idea is to use it from Java facebook-sdk.
But at the moment I am just trying to run a simple request to fetch a public event

[https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/{event_id}?access_token={access_token}](https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/%7Bevent_id%7D?access_token=%7Baccess_token%7D)

But I am getting this error:
{
"error": {
"message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'XXXXX' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api%22),
"type": "GraphMethodException",
"code": 100,
"error_subcode": 33,
"fbtrace_id": "Apc-nisB6j0fD2LB--0gTSa"
}
}

I wonder if I need more permissions from organiser of the event, but the event says
"Public  · Anyone on or off Facebook"

So why would we need permissions? I just need to fetch some data from the event like name, description and cover url.. I could do it by simple parsing the source code of the page, but API will be much more efficient. Could it be because its just postman or browser?

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone here? Please

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event: _"Access to Events on Users and Pages is only available to Facebook Marketing Partners."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Facebook Marketing Partner status to get info about events.

All you need is:

1. App with "in development" status,
2. User access token obtained from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Create a `GET` request, for example

```
https://graph.facebook.com/**EVENT-ID-HERE**?fields=cover,name,description,start_time,end_time,id,attending_count,created_time,declined_count,interested_count,maybe_count,event_times,place,updated_time,ticket_uri,type,discount_code_enabled,noreply_count&access_token=**ACCESS-TOKEN**
```

Its worth to note, that

1. You should be "Interested" or "Going" to an event which data you want to GET info;
2. Event ID's should be extracted manually.

For the idea I personally do in this way:

1. Copy paste all event links to google sheet (and pressing interest)
2. With `=SPLIT[cell;"/"]` sheet formula I extract event IDs
3. Then I run script, that gets all the info Event contains.

Sorry for my unprofessional way of explaining things, I am not a Developer and I found this question because I am looking for answer about how to extract event cover photo without a specific App status. :))

I hope that this helps or anyone can explain this better.

Comment: This no longer works in 2024 for me at least.  Does it work for you?

Comment: It stopped working for me around 13th of March 2024.